# Get the music genres in YouTube

Tags: youtube-api

When we view the YouTube page, and click Music, we are able to see them on different genre's like "Rap", "Rock", "Country", etc.

How can I retrieve this data (the genre-wise listing of videos) using the YouTube Apis.?

Comment: Have resolved this ??? , i am interested in the same subject

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is using the Topics API integration with V3 of the API. Take a look at the [videos.list() API call](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list). Plug in these values:

- part: topicDetails
- id: fWNaR-rxAic
- fields: items/topicDetails/topicIds

The ID of that video corresponds to [Carly Rae Jepsen's "Call Me Maybe"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fWNaR-rxAic). When you look at the JSON response, you'll see a list of topic IDs:

[ "/m/015f7",
 "/m/0h55y27",
 "/m/0gkxzs6",
 "/m/064t9" ]

These are Freebase machine IDs. You would then make a Freebase API call to retrieve information about that particular topic. For instance, [/m/064t9 corresponds to "Pop Music"](http://www.freebase.com/m/064t9).

Thise method won't work for 100% of videos on YouTube; [Metallica's "Whiskey in a Jar"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=boanuwUMNNQ) only returns topics for the song and the band, however, [Britney Spear's "I Want to Go"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-sxSd1uwoU) correctly returns a machine ID for "Pop Music".

The reason for this is that the Topic is often machine generated, not human curated (though we do quality checks). We did a [Google I/O talk about how this works](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wf_77z1H-vQ). The good news is that once you DO have a machine ID, it's very easy to find other videos by topic ID. Our [samples demonstrate how to do this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python#topics).

Comment: Do you know where can i find the other topics IDs for other music genres and documentaries categories  ???

Answer (score 1):

In freebase you can ask for music genre mids. For example in: http://www.freebase.com/search?query=rock you get that /m/06by7 = rock. With this id you do a query on youtube and get videos regarding this genre;

Try it https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#try-it with this conditions:

```
part: snippet
topicId: /m/06by7
```

Comment: @david_adler and what can be used for this instead ?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering about this now (2017) freebase is deprecated and so instead you should use the list currently provided here: https://gist.github.com/stpe/2951130dfc8f1d0d1a2ad736bef3b703

Ikai Lan is still correct that the part is topicDetails to get this information from the API.