# Get genre from youtube ID

Tags: python, youtube

```
def get_data(key, region, *ids):
    url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id={ids}&key={api_key}"
    r = requests.get(url.format(ids=",".join(ids), api_key=key))
    js = r.json()
    items = js["items"]
    cat_js = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videoCategories?part=snippet&regionCode={}&key={}".format(region,
    key)).json()
    categories = {d['id']: d["snippet"]['title'] for d in cat_js["items"]}
    for item in items:
        yield item["snippet"]["title"], categories[item["snippet"]["categoryId"]]
```

I have the above function to get the youtube category and video name. Is there a way to get the genre of a music video as well, i.e. Pop, Rock, House, etc.? Please help!

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if the genre are flagged - probably not.

If not, I would suggest two options.

**Easy one**:

- Get a list of music genres ([here](http://www.musicgenreslist.com/) for example, but you can define yours according to your task)
- Each time you get the title, separate the artist name and the music name
- Query wikipedia with the artist name and check if some music genres are quoted.
- If existing, query wikipedia with the lyric name to check if genres are quoted.

PS : You can quote other site if needed (more accurate for instance). As another open source database, check http://musicbrainz.org/ which provides tags to each artist. You definitely have to automate the query to those pages - which is easy with Wikipedia, thus the first proposition ([check that](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wikipedia/)).

**Hard one:**

- Get a training set of music labeled with their genres
- Extract audio features
- Train an classifier with the previous features
- Classify any new music thanks to this classifier (For example, for a given music, associate a probability to each genre - and define thresold(s) to keep some of them)
- If done well, get hired by major music companies - some have tried with not-so-good results

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But doesn't youtube contain the genre field as well? I remember seeing lists of songs by genre on my homepage.

Comment: Because if youtube API can provide it, I wouldn't have do so much scraping.

Comment: [Here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_category_keyword_browsing), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698040/youtube-api-v3-where-can-i-find-a-list-of-each-videocategoryid) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453917/get-the-music-genres-in-youtube) what I've found on Google - In case you tried, which problem(s) have you encountered? I might have misunderstood your question

Comment: The json that is retrieved does not contain the genre field in it.

Comment: Plus the freebase is deprecated.

Comment: also if I look at the wikipedia page of an artist, there are multiple genres associated. I just want the genre of a particular track of the artist. Can you suggest something here?